# exceptions arose integrating matlab and netbeans

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans, unsupported-class-version

While trying to run matlab hello world code inside java I get some exceptions as follows. I don't know to rectify the exceptions.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: project/Project : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:143)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:281)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:209)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:324)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:269)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:337)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would mean that your version of java is too old and you need to update it. On windows no problem. On old Macs impossible.